# vectorization of matlab for-loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, determinants

I am looking for proper vectorization of following matlab function to eliminate for-loop and gain speed by multithreading.

`size(A)` = `N`-by-`N`, where `30 <= N <= 60`

`1e4 <= numIter <= 1e6`

```
function val=permApproxStochSquare(A,numIter)
%// A       ... input square non-negative matrix
%// numIter ... number of interations

N=size(A,1);

alpha=zeros(numIter,1);
for curIter=1:numIter
    U=randn(N,N);
    B=U.*sqrt(A);
    alpha(curIter)=det(B)^2;
end

val=mean(alpha);
end
```

Comment: For large N, using `parfor` might be an option.

Comment: @Daniel Yes parfor is simple and good solution, but i need solution without Parallel Computing Toolbox (parfor)

Comment: Beside a parfor, I only think of precomputing `sqrt(A)` outside the loop. `parfor` can be used without the Parallel Computing Toolbox but you don't have any flexibility.

Comment: For such small matrices, `parfor` probably won't help. Unless anyone has an idea to vectorize multiple calls of `det`, I think there is no chance for a significant improvement.

Comment: Also, you could precompute `U` outside the loop by `U = randn(N,N,numIter)` and then access it in the loop by `U(:,;,curIter)` which might save some time. Additionally, you could try `det(U.*sqrt(A))^2`.

Comment: On vectorizing the determinant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10861142/2678563

Comment: @JaBe ... this vectorizing approach (http://stackoverflow.com/q/10861142/2678563) does not produce any significant speed up over standard for-loop.

Comment: @michal: Which of the answers did you try? There are two totally different approaches.

Comment: @Daniel d = arrayfun(@(w) det(U(:, :, w)), 1 : size(U, 3)); vs d = zeros(size(U,3),1); for w = 1 : length(d), d(w) = det(U(:, :, w)); end;

Comment: @michal: as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10871627/2732801) confirms, arrayfun is typically not faster than a for loop. I also took a look at the [option 1 from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862032/2732801). While beeing a great idea for small matrices, it is totally infeasible for matrices of that size.

Comment: If you are looking to port this to GPU, you can gain good speedup if you store the frequently used `sqrt(A)` in shared memory and generate random numbers on the fly inside kernels.

Comment: @Divakar: Could you be more specific. Any example?

Comment: @michal Ops, forgot to mention, I had in CUDA in mind. Look into it, it supports shared memory.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the discussion in the comment to two versions of the code which slightly improve the performance:

Using multiple ideas from the comments, the code needs roughly 1/3 less time:

```
N=size(A,1);
%precompute sqrt(A)
sA=sqrt(A);
alpha=zeros(numIter,1);
parfor curIter=1:numIter
    %vectorizing rand did not improve the performance because it increased communitcation when combined with parfor
    U=randn(N,N);
    B=U.*sA;
    alpha(curIter)=det(B);
end
%moved calculation out of the loop to vectorize
val=mean(alpha.^2);
```

Another approach, vectorize as far as possible using a `for` loop only did small improvemens to the perfrmance:

```
N=size(A,1);
%precompute sqrt(A)
sA=sqrt(A);
alpha=zeros(numIter,1);
%using a for, a vectorized rand outside the loop is faster.
U=randn(N,N,numIter);
B=bsxfun(@times,U,sA);
for curIter=1:numIter
    alpha(curIter)=det(B(:,:,curIter));
end
val=mean(alpha.^2);
```

Comment: Completely agree ... Moreover, 2nd approach produce big memory requirements.

Comment: What about GPU? Will be possible to effectively run this code on NVIDIA CUDA from MATLAB via PCT?

Comment: I have no experience, besides it would require the parallel computing toolbox.